# Programmatically editing apk files in java

Tags: java, android, apk, zip

This question gets a little complicated so please bear with me:
I have an apk file I am attempting to modify programmatically after installation. I am editing it with another app. I first attempted to do this with the built in java classes for zip file management but when i attempt to completely copy all the files except the file i want to modify and change the file i want to modify the app will not run anymore. I assume this is because of signing or something but when I do the same thing with winRAR (unzip all files, create a new zip archive, copy all files into new zip archive with normal compression) and ssh the new apk into my /data/app folder, it works fine. My question is why this is happening. I think it may have to do with zip headers or something like that does anyone have any ideas?

PS: this is an example of the java process i am using to re-write the zip file:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("This is the apk containing the asset I want to use to replace the other asset"));
ZipEntry e;
while((e = in.getNextEntry()) != null)
{
    if(e.getName().equals("asset i want to use to replace the other asset"))
        break;
}
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("the output zip file"));
ZipInputStream original = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("the apk i am trying to modify"));
ZipEntry f;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
while((f = original.getNextEntry()) != null)
{
    if(!f.getName().equals("the asset i want to replace"))
    {
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(f.getName()));
        int len;
        while ((len = original.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        original.closeEntry();
        out.closeEntry();
    }
    else
    {
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(e.getName()));
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.closeEntry();
    }
}
in.close();
out.close();
original.close();
```

I have run this process on the android system and on windows using regular software, i can open the output in winRAR and it appears to be the same except for the asset file i changed.

Comment: Name any legitimate reason for doing this.

Comment: @CommonsWare because i want to replace some of the images in the game with some of my custom images for my own purposes. Also because i am still learning android development and thought this would be a good experiment to help me learn things about android. And also, why not?

Comment: How are you getting the other apk from your app?  it seems like you'd be able to do this for an apk provided you were making a copy... is that what you're doing in code?

Comment: @JRaymond Yes I am attempting to make a copy of the original apk but with one image file changed in the assets folder. It seems like it would work but for some reason it always crashes apon startup.

Comment: I don't think that it'll work because you would also need to sign the APK file on the fly then. If you modify it, the hash check will fail...

Comment: @Bob yes but the fact that you can do the same thing with winrar leads me to believe its possible

Answer (score 0):

The only one thing you should know is how works signing apk tool (work around check sums - they are zip entries. A target folder is META-INF with CERT.RSA - there's present encoded checksum and else debug info, CERT.SF and MANIFEST.MF - with SHA1-Digest - Base64 encoded hashes (they are easy to detect by yourself)). 
But this is a real hacking! That code can be useful (and used by many "smart programmers" for dinamically changing of picture of application for ex.) and can be dangerous - because your apk file can be increased to GB sizes - if you'll write so.

This trick shouldn't be spreaded between world-wide comunity people and I think - it will be kept in short circles of programmers.